# Android SDK Manager freezes after installation of OSX 10.11 El Capitan public Beta

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-sdk-manager, osx-elcapitan

I've just installed the public beta of El Capitan OS X (10.11).

The only issue I'm having after the upgrade installation from Yosemite is Android SDK Manager.

When I launch Android SDK Manager from within Android Studio 1.2.2 it checks and parses via a network call. After clicking on any of the individual modules, the SDK Manager freezes and you get a colourful wheel of death. The only way is to force close the application.

I've tried restarting the MacBook Pro and force quitting and relaunching the SDK manager and still the issue persists. SDK Manager was working without issues prior to the upgrade of 10.11

Edit: I've noticed that none of the emulators work with El Capitan as

```
CPU acceleration status: HAX is not installed on this machine (/dev/HAX is missing).
```

I've tried using Genymotion and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the latest update from Apple OS X El Capitan Public Beta version 2 (15A225f) fixes the issue with Android SDK Manager and it functions properly now.

Side note: The Android Emulators still don't work and nor does genymotion as still getting this message.

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX is not installed on this machine (/dev/HAX is missing).
```

Comment: i get /dev/HAX missing after every reboot in el capitan final but after reinstalling hax everything works well... until i reboot :)

Answer (score 4):

I was in trouble about the same thing, too.

Workaround fix, I use `no-ui` option:

```
$ android update sdk --no-ui
```

Other option is available here: http://tools.android.com/recent/updatingsdkfromcommand-line